# kibana is not grouping by time

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

I'm getting into Kibana. Therefore I set it up to collect some logs. Unfortunately I seem to have a grouping problem.
When creating the index pattern I set "time filter field name" to `@timestamp`.

Nevertheless it seems not to be grouping as I'm expecting it. In my case I would expect 2 groupings. 
One for `Sep 30, 2019 @ 18:30:51.485` and one for `Sep 30, 2019 @ 18:30:51.484`.

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Kibana **Discovery** the documents dont get grouped by their timestamp. Each row represents a document no matter if there are documents with the same timestamp value.

Take a look at Elasticsearch's aggregations (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html). With them you can group (*bucket*) documents by particular values. But you would do that via the REST API in the Kibana **DevTools**.

This skeleton of a query may get you **started**:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
   "aggs":{
     "my_agg":{
       "terms":{
          "field": "@timestamp"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

This will perform a match_all query and group/bucket the hits by their timestamp value.

Another, more visual way of displaying buckets/groups is to create a Data Table visualization with the respective aggregation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is a really helpfull start